# Can I travel 100% safely with only my Identity Card from Romania to Svalbard?

Tags: norway, romania, identity-cards

This is my first trip outside the country, never been on a plane before.. and at the same time I’m going alone. So I’m scared and worried and trying to do as much research as possible. Many sources say that I should be able to go with my identity card, but our ministry’s site still recommends a passport and that stresses me. A passport isn’t free and I don’t want to throw money around.

So is there any 0,0001% chance that I could be stopped because I don’t have a passport?

Yes, I’ve read the Dutch Identity Card post before I came here, but it’s not the same thing, at least that’s how I see it. And I want to make sure it works for my country too.

Comment: Timatic also says a passport is required https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: @Traveller I can't find anything in Timatic indicating that a passport is required or that a national id card does not suffice. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Mihail, if you think there is anything in your situation, which differs from the question about Dutch id cards, you will probably have to tell us exactly what.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Svalbard? It's a rather unusual choice of first destination, and also a very expensive one.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbo Entering ‘National ID card’ under ‘Secondary Document Held’ resulted in ‘passport required’. But perhaps I’m misunderstanding - happy to delete my comment

Comment: @Traveller You have to be more verbose about what you enter Timatic. I am assuming that OP is a Romanian citizen with a Romanian national id card going from Romania to Norway. No matter if I ask Timatic if the person can travel with a passport, a national id card or passport *and* national id card (as secondary document), Timatic correctly answers with a green tick and '*Yes*, The travel documents held by the traveler are sufficient!'.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Sorry for the late answer but I didn’t notice the comment section until now. Well.. simply put, that it’s not the same country. And if it would be perfectly fine to go with only an ID why does my country still recommend a passport even when I can use an ID.. I think I’ll be so worried that I’ll end up making one..

Comment: @jpatokal Because of love. And yes I wouldn’t be able to afford to stay there in a hotel. I think this pretty much answers the question.

Comment: A national id card from any EU or EEA country, be it Romania or the Netherlands, is sufficient as travel document to enter Norway (or any other EU or EEA country). If your ministry says something else and you want to know why, I suppose you have to contact and ask the ministry.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo I too entered the traveller details in full as you stated. I got a different answer to you.
Norway - Destination Passport

Passport required.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Visit Svalbard website](https://en.visitsvalbard.com/visitor-information/travel-information/how-to-travel-to-svalbard):

> All guests with a foreign citizenship MUST bring their passports or national ID-card.

[The website of the Governor of Svalbard](https://www.sysselmannen.no/en/Visitors/Entry-and-residence/) says:

> Everyone may, in principle, travel to Svalbard, and foreign citizens do not need a visa or a work or residence permit from Norwegian authorities in order to settle in Svalbard. Foreign citizens with visa requirements to the Schengen area do, however, need a valid Schengen visa if they travel through Schengen on their way to or from Svalbard. It is required with two entries in the traveller's visa to be able to return to the Schengen area (mainland Norway) after the stay at Svalbard.

(note: most of this doesn't apply to you, because as a Romanian citizen you have no visa requirements to enter the Schengen area)

and also says:

> According to the Schengen regulations, all passengers passing through a Schengen boarder shall be controlled. Since Svalbard is not part of the Schengen area, everyone travelling between Svalbard and the Norwegian mainland must be controlled.

This section concludes with a link to more information from 
[the Norwegian government](https://www.regjeringen.no/en/historical-archive/Stoltenbergs-2nd-Government/Ministry-of-Justice-and-the-Police/Nyheter-og-pressemeldinger/pressemeldinger/2010/new-rules-for-travellers-between-svalbar/id628539/):

> Since Svalbard is not part of the Schengen area, anyone travelling between Svalbard and the Norwegian mainland must be controlled. From 1 February 2011 travelleres will be controlled both at entry and exit.
>   [...]
>   Passports or national identity cards will satisfy Schengen regulatory requirements for identity verification.

Your national ID should be fine.

(Although if you have some specific reason for believing that your situation is different from that with a Dutch ID card, you should explain why so that people can verify.)

Comment: I do not have any specific reason other than being scared that it won’t be enough. And since I can’t find any post from a Romanian going there I can’t feel at ease. I want to make sure ‘it will be fine’ rather than ‘it should be fine’ ..

Comment: @MihailPopescu well the main reason I said "should" rather than will is because you seemed to have some (undisclosed) reason for thinking your situation is more complicated, and I didn't want to declare it irrelevant without knowing what it is. If you're just a bit nervous, well I've shown you the links above from multiple official sources - you can draw your own conclusions from them, but to me it seems clear that you will be able to travel with your ID card.

Comment: @MihailPopescu but obviously, I'm not a Norwegian immigration lawyer. If you want **absolute** certainty I suggest you either find somebody who is, or [contact the office of the Governor of Svalbard](https://www.sysselmannen.no/en/Toppmeny/The-Governor-of-Svalbard/Contact-us/). Or get a passport.